# Python graphing issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

Hey guys I am reading in data from an Arduino processing it and using this code I found to try and plot the data live. I have edited this code to make it work with two sets of data coming in and I want a line for each set of data. I have tried a lot of things to get this code to work but right now this is where I am stuck. I am testing data using [100,110] but when I run the code I get

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py in execfile(fname, *where)
173             else:
174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Arduino/Graphing_22.py in <module>()
304 if __name__ == '__main__':
305     app = wx.PySimpleApp()
--> 306     app.frame = GraphFrame()
307     app.frame.Show()
308     app.MainLoop()

 /Users/Tyler/Desktop/Arduino/Graphing_22.py in __init__(self)
 87         self.create_menu()
 88         self.create_status_bar() 
 ---> 89         self.create_main_panel()
 90 
 91         self.redraw_timer = wx.Timer(self)

/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Arduino/Graphing_22.py in create_main_panel(self)
109         self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
110 
--> 111         self.init_plot()
112         self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
113 

/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Arduino/Graphing_22.py in init_plot(self)
180         #adding a line to the plot

181         self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
--> 182                                        self.data[1],
183                                        linewidth=1,
184                                        color=(1, 2, 0),

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is really long for this so I will post what I think is relevant. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks for the help.

```
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title)

    self.datagen = DataGen()
    self.data = [self.datagen.next()]
    #splitting data at '
    #self.data = [self.datagen.next().split(",")
    self.paused = False


    self.create_menu()
    self.create_status_bar()
    self.create_main_panel()

    self.redraw_timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_redraw_timer, self.redraw_timer)        
    self.redraw_timer.Start(REFRESH_INTERVAL_MS)

def init_plot(self):
    self.dpi = 100
    self.fig = Figure((3.0, 3.0), dpi=self.dpi)

    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.axes.set_axis_bgcolor('black')
    self.axes.set_title('Arduino Serial Data', size=12)

    pylab.setp(self.axes.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    pylab.setp(self.axes.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)

    # plot the data as a line series, and save the reference 
    # to the plotted line series
    #
    self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
                                    self.data[0], 
                                    linewidth=1,
                                    color=(1, 1, 0),
                                    )[0]

    #adding a line to the plot
    self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
                                   self.data[1],
                                   linewidth=1,
                                   color=(1, 2, 0),
                                    )[1]
```

Comment: what is `self.datagen.next()` returning?

Comment: self.datagen.next() for testing purposes is returning [100,110], now if I take the brackets off of that line of code it turn into a whole new sets of errors. What I am passing to self.datagen.next() is already a list, but if I dont use brackets I get another error saying list object has no attribute set_xdata

Comment: so your data is a list of size 1 with a string `'[100,110]'` or an other list `[100,110]`?

Comment: If I am understanding what you are asking correctly I pass a list [100,110] to [self.datagen.next()] so I think that would look like [[100,110]] sorry my python is pretty shaky

Comment: yes, something like that. The list constructor where you are creating your data list, only has one element.  That element being whatever was being returned by `self.datagen.next()`

Comment: ah ok that totally makes sense. So let me make sure I understand the list I am passing to self.datagen.next() only has one element not 2 like I think it has correct?

Comment: Can you make your question title more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `IndexError: list index out of range` indicates that for line `182` `data[1]` is out of range - this means there is no `data[1]` element (data is len 1 or len 0). You need to find the line in your code where you build the `data` list to understand why this is the case.

Comment: I am building the data in a separate program. When I run that program that will print out the data it prints [100,110]. This tells me that there is data in elements 0 and 1. Right?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "prints [100,110]". can you do `print data` before line 182 and tell me what the output is?